# Angular/Typescript - Boolean variable not updating on .subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, .net-core, angular-httpclient

I have this function on the server side, forced to return true for the moment:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        [HttpGet("cPasaAJefeVentas")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CPasaAJefeVentas(string idPais, string idCompania, string idSalesorg, string idDivision, string idUser, decimal porcentaje)
        {
          
            return Ok(true);

        }
```

This is how you call it on the client side inside a service:

```
cPasaAJefeVentas(idPais: string , idCompania:string, idSalesOrg:string, idDivision:string, idUser:string, porcentaje:number) {
        return this.http.get(this.altapedidosserveruri + 'cPasaAJefeVentas?=' + idPais + '&idCompania=' + idCompania + '&idSalesOrg=' + idSalesOrg + '&idDivision=' + idDivision + '&idUser=' + idUser + '&porcentaje=' + porcentaje);
    }
```

And here is where i'm having issues right now:

```
 cPasaJefeVentas(): boolean {
    let descuentoDiscrecional: number = 5;
    let res: boolean = null;
    this.altaPedidosService
      .cPasaAJefeVentas(this.pedidoObjeto.idPais, this.pedidoObjeto.idCompania,
        this.pedidoObjeto.idSalesOrg, this.pedidoObjeto.idDivision, this.loggedService.logged.UserName, descuentoDiscrecional)
      .subscribe((result: boolean) => (
        console.log(result),
        res = result
      ))
    return res;
  }
```

The console.log(result) prints TRUE, which is correct, but then i want to asignt that returned value to the "res" variable, and its not working, because it's still null when it exits the .susbscribe.

**I want to know what am i doing wrong here? Why isnt the value of the "res" variable updating like it should?**

Comment: because javascript is async.. and you are returning `null` :)

Answer (score 0):

Your service is returning an **Observable** response. **Observables are asynchronous** and you can't guarantee when the response will receive. So, modify your method to return **Observable** response as well. Your code would get modified like this

```js
 cPasaJefeVentas(): Observable<boolean> {
    let descuentoDiscrecional: number = 5;
    let res: boolean = null;
    let response$ = this.altaPedidosService
      .cPasaAJefeVentas(this.pedidoObjeto.idPais, this.pedidoObjeto.idCompania,
        this.pedidoObjeto.idSalesOrg, this.pedidoObjeto.idDivision, this.loggedService.logged.UserName, descuentoDiscrecional)
      .subscribe((result: boolean) => (
        console.log(result),
        res = result
      ));
      
      return response$;
  }
```

And in the template you may apply **async** pipe to show the observable value, for example

```
<p>{{cPasaJefeVentas() | async}}</p>
```